# in Android, when a service and activity use the same static class, is the class 'created' twice?

Tags: android

this is just a general knowledge question - out of curiosity...

In Android, when an activity and a service use the same static class (i.e. singleton) does the service end up getting its own 'version' of the class ?

For example, I put all of my global constants into a static class. Are these memory locations created once for activities and again for separate processes such as a service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A single process with a single, unified memory space is created for your activities and services so there will only be one instance of your static class. Note that this is the *default* behavior and there are ways to, for instance, have your service run in a different process. Then all bets are off and static variables are almost certainly not the best path forward for your implementation.

Comment: right, I read that a service can be in a separate process - this case particularly peaked my interest.

Comment: Key point: _can be_ in a separate process. But you have to explicitly set it up in the manifest to enable it.

Comment: lets see what the answer is... http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/writing-contentprovider-wrapper-methods/#comment-1062

Comment: jwei512 on that wordpress blog is apparently not active so I will mark this as solved for now. Note that I have put a bunch of constants into a static class and a service in a separate process was able to access those constants.